# WSO2 "Use Data Source Factory" option of JNDI datasources

Tags: postgresql, wso2, datasource, wso2-esb

When configuring datasource one can check "Use Data Source Factory" checkbox in "Expose as JNDI datasource" section. Documentation explains it as follows:

> To make the datasource accessible from an external environment, you must use a data source factory. When this option is selected, a reference object will be created with the defined datasource properties. The data source factory will create the datasource instance based on the values of the reference object when accessing the datasource from an external environment. In the datasource configuration, this is set as follows: 
>       < jndiConfig useDataSourceFactory="true" >

However it sounds completely unclear to me. What could be an "external environment" here?

**Can someone explain more detailed the actual difference between set&unset checkbox state?**

I use such JNDI datasource in custom mediator to connect to Postgres9.3 and see the difference as follows:

- checkbox "on": no transaction markup (BEGIN/COMMIT/ROLLBACK) is issued, but new records are always added into database, like autocommit is on
- checkbox "off": new records are added from time to time, BEGIN and ROLLBACK statements are issued implicitly (displayed in Postgres log)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the effect of this setting is instantiating specific connection pool (org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource) for each mediator requesting it. 
Otherwise, all mediators use the same connection pool.

In my case, the problem appeared due to the fact that connection settings are not cleared up once it returns into the pool. Some mediators have set autoCommit=false for some of connections and here the behaviour became undetermined: connections still having default settings successfully saved data in DB, while connections with autoCommit=false issued BEGIN/ROLLBACK statements (thus saving nothing in DB).